# Clicking 'I will edit to explain how' leads to non-responsive edit page

Tags: bug, edits, duplicate-questions, responsive-design

When your question has pending duplicate votes, you're shown a banner which ends with:

> No, my question is different. I will edit to explain how.

Clicking the edit link will lead to a non-responsive edit page (left), while clicking the normal edit link under the question gives a responsive edit page (right), as expected.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The bug is that the edit link below the post loads the inline post editor, without changing the page, while the button in the notice redirects you to the full editing page, which has not yet received its responsive makeover. They should probably both do the same thing.